# Different agent pool or demands for the same Azure Pipeline based on trigger

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipeline written in YAML which runs from a CI trigger whenever changes are made to the `master` branch.  It can also be manually triggered from Pull Requests or by users against any branch.

Due to the use of a number of licensed components, the build from `master` needs to run on a specific agent.  The other builds do not, and in fact I would rather they run on other agent(s).

So my question is, is there any way to specify a different agent/pool within the YAML pipeline based on what triggered the build, or what branch the build is building?  I'd like this to be behaviour which is configured in the pipeline permanently, rather than requiring users to update the YAML on each branch they wish to build elsewhere.

I can't see anything obvious in the sections of the documentation on the pool/demands/condition keywords.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this by putting the `steps` for the job into a template, and then creating a set of jobs in the pipeline with different `condition` entries, so that we can set `demands` based on those conditions.

A skeleton version looks like this:

```yaml
- stage: Build
    jobs:
    - job: TopicBranchAndPullRequestBuild
      condition: or(startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/topic'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/pull'))
      displayName: 'Build topic Branch or Pull Request'

      pool:
        name: the-one-and-only-pool
        demands:
          - HasLicensedComponents -equals false
      steps:
        - template: build-template.yml

    - job: MasterAndReleaseBranchBuild
      condition: or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release'))
      displayName: 'Build master or release Branch'
      pool:
        name: the-one-and-only-pool
        demands:
          - HasLicensedComponents -equals true
      steps:
        - template: build-template.yml
```

Obviously the values given here are for example only, but otherwise this is what I have working.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try expressions? I've used this with success on variable groups so it might work on agent pools.

```
- ${{ if eq(variables['build.SourceBranchName'], 'prod') }}:
  - pool: Host1
- ${{ if eq(variables['build.SourceBranchName'], 'staging') }}:
  - pool: Host2
- ${{ if not(and(eq(variables['build.SourceBranchName'], 'staging'), eq(variables['build.SourceBranchName'], 'prod'))) }}:
  - pool: Host3
```

Credit for original workaround for dynamically pulling variable groups here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3702#issuecomment-574278829

Answer (score 0):

The pool keyword specifies which pool to use for a **job** of the pipeline. A pool specification also holds information about the **job's** strategy for running. You can specify a pool at the pipeline, stage, or job level. The pool specified at the lowest level of the hierarchy is used to run the job.

> is there any way to specify a different agent/pool within the YAML
>   pipeline based on what triggered the build, or what branch the build
>   is building?

For this issue , you can create different yaml files for different branches, specify different agent pools in the corresponding yaml file.

You can switch to the yaml file of different branches in pipeline with the option shown below:

[image]

Comment: To be clearer, I want to be able to create a rule in the pipeline which forces it to run on a specific host when run from the `master` branch, and allow it to run on anything but that host from anywhere else.  I'd like that to be automatic, rather than requiring people to update the yaml manually in each branch.  I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: You can try to implement it with two jobs. The first job can determine the source branch through the power shell task. If it is `master`, set the variable `vm` to the name of the agent. Then set the pool in the second job to: `vmImage: $(vm)`

Comment: @James Telfer Not get your latest information, is the workaround in the above comment helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
parameters:
  - name: self_hosted_agent
    displayName: Choose your pool agent
    type: string
    default: windows-latest
    values:
    - windows-latest
    - self-hosted
  - name: agent_name
    displayName: Choose your agent
    type: string
    default: 'Laptop Clint'
    values:
    - 'Laptop Clint'
    - 'Laptop Eastwood'

variables:
  - name: pool_agent_key
    ${{ if eq(parameters.self_hosted_agent, 'windows-latest') }}:
      value: vmImage
    ${{ if eq(parameters.self_hosted_agent, 'self-hosted') }}:
      value: name
  - name: pool_agent_value
    ${{ if eq(parameters.self_hosted_agent, 'windows-latest') }}:
      value: windows-latest
    ${{ if eq(parameters.self_hosted_agent, 'self-hosted') }}:
      value: Iot-Windows
  - name: agent_name
    value: ${{ parameters.agent_name }}

stages:
  - stage: build
    displayName: Build    
    pool: 
      ${{ variables.pool_agent_key }}: ${{ variables.pool_agent_value }}
      ${{ if eq(parameters.self_hosted_agent, 'self-hosted') }}:
        demands: 
          - agent.name -equals ${{ variables.agent_name }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).